# form size to different resolutions

Tags: winforms, size

hoping you could help me out with the sizing if my forms. on my school laptop the form fits nicely to the resolution. however, on my personal laptop, the form does not fit the larger res and for some reason is more zoomed. I have sent pictures too

Answer (score 0):

You get you screen resolution with following code:

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
```

you could adjust the position from every control in the form_load event with `Control.Location` or the size with `Control.Size` depending on the width and height of your screen.

For example

`label1.Location.X = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - 100;`

`label1.Location.Y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - 50;`

If you want your control to always be fullscreen, you could also add `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;` in the form_load event. then its easier to adjust the positions of the controls depending on screen size.